# top memory used and percent don't match

Tags: memory, mysql, amazon-ec2, top

I have an ec2 server and sometimes I have memory issues - I've had the mysql process killed due to out of memory.  This breaks my website and game and sometimes it takes me hours or days to notice :(.  Right now I have lamp, wordpress, and my java mmorpg running on the server.  I know my mmorpg server takes quite a bit of RAM to hold all of the entities and data.

I have **1 GB of RAM** and **1 GB of swap**.  Here is my top output currently.

[image: top output]

What I don't understand is why if my **java process is 7.6%** and my current **mysqld is 1.9%** how I am even close?  It says **956MB of Mem** used and **378MB of Swap** used - those numbers seem real.  How is that even close to 7.6 + 1.9%?

Is there some way I can monitor my memory a bit better or something that I can configure on mysql, so it does not run OOM?  I am pretty sure there is no leak in my java server code - but not 100% sure.

Sorry for all of the questions - after coding my mmorpg from scratch for over 5 years now I want to make sure my server is ready to handle a decent playerbase.

**EDIT requested in comments**

**free** output

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       1019336     937316      82020        344       8920      45120
-/+ buffers/cache:     883276     136060
Swap:      1048572     417708     630864
```

**ps aux** output

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0  19644     0 ?        Ss   Aug14   0:00 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug14   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug14   0:08 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug14   0:00 [kworker/0:0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Aug14   0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug14   1:51 [rcu_sched]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug14   0:00 [rcu_bh]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug14   0:00 [migration/0]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug14   0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Aug14   0:00 [netns]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Aug14   0:00 [perf]
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug14   0:00 [xenwatch]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug14   0:00 [xenbus]
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug14   0:19 [kworker/0:1]
root       128  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug14   0:00 [khungtaskd]
root       129  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Aug14   0:00 [writeback]
root       131  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Aug14   0:00 [ksmd]
root       132  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Aug14   0:00 [khugepaged]
root       133  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Aug14   0:00 [crypto]
root       134  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Aug14   0:00 [kintegrityd]
root       135  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Aug14   0:00 [bioset]
root       137  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Aug14   0:00 [kblockd]
root       488  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Aug14   0:00 [md]
root       616  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug14   0:46 [kswapd0]
root       617  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Aug14   0:00 [vmstat]
root       689  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug14   0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
root       708  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Aug14   0:00 [kthrotld]
root       748  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Aug14   0:00 [bioset]
root       752  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Aug14   0:00 [deferwq]
root      1374  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Aug14   0:00 [ata_sff]
root      1387  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug14   0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root      1396  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Aug14   0:00 [scsi_tmf_0]
root      1399  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug14   0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root      1412  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Aug14   0:00 [scsi_tmf_1]
root      1470  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug14   0:34 [jbd2/xvda1-8]
root      1471  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Aug14   0:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
root      1499  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Aug14   0:00 [kworker/0:1H]
root      1517  0.0  0.0  11424    28 ?        Ss   Aug14   0:00 /sbin/udevd -d
root      1590  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Aug14   0:00 [kpsmoused]
root      1641  0.0  0.0  11312    32 ?        S    Aug14   0:00 /sbin/udevd -d
root      1827  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug14   0:00 [kauditd]
root      1882  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Aug14   0:00 [ipv6_addrconf]
root      2035  0.0  0.0   9360   628 ?        Ss   Aug14   0:00 /sbin/dhclient -q -lf /var/lib/dhclient/dhclient-eth0.leases -pf /var/run/dhclient-eth0.pid eth0
root      2087  0.0  0.0  46536    36 ?        S<sl Aug14   0:00 auditd
root      2108  0.0  0.0 247464     0 ?        Sl   Aug14   0:00 /sbin/rsyslogd -i /var/run/syslogd.pid -c 5
dbus      2137  0.0  0.0  21792     4 ?        Ss   Aug14   0:00 dbus-daemon --system
root      2266  0.0  0.0  77840   780 ?        Ss   Aug14   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
root      2327  0.0  0.0 115344    28 ?        S    Aug14   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --basedir=/usr --user=mysql
mysql     2536  0.6  1.3 886436 13936 ?        Sl   Aug14  83:28 /usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
root      2585  0.0  0.0  88992   552 ?        Ss   Aug14   0:18 sendmail: accepting connections
smmsp     2594  0.0  0.0  80440   400 ?        Ss   Aug14   0:00 sendmail: Queue runner@01:00:00 for /var/spool/clientmqueue
root      2605  0.0  0.1 431276  1284 ?        Ss   Aug14   0:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
root      2616  0.0  0.0 119516   768 ?        Ss   Aug14   0:03 crond
root      2630  0.0  0.0  17068    88 ?        Ss   Aug14   0:00 /usr/sbin/atd
root      2653  0.0  0.0   4312    32 tty1     Ss+  Aug14   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty1
root      2655  0.0  0.0   6460    32 ttyS0    Ss+  Aug14   0:00 /sbin/agetty ttyS0 9600 vt100-nav
root      2657  0.0  0.0   4312    32 tty2     Ss+  Aug14   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty2
root      2660  0.0  0.0   4312    32 tty3     Ss+  Aug14   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty3
root      2664  0.0  0.0   4312    32 tty4     Ss+  Aug14   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty4
root      2666  0.0  0.0   4312    32 tty5     Ss+  Aug14   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty5
root      2668  0.0  0.0  10876    32 ?        S    Aug14   0:00 /sbin/udevd -d
root      2669  0.0  0.0   4312    32 tty6     Ss+  Aug14   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty6
root      2797  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug14   0:12 [kworker/u30:2]
ntp       2821  0.0  0.1  29288  1808 ?        Ss   Aug14   0:01 ntpd -u ntp:ntp -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g
apache   12405  0.1  4.2 471264 42920 ?        S    Aug22   1:08 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   12412  0.1  3.6 466372 37440 ?        S    Aug22   1:07 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   12413  0.1  4.1 487140 42788 ?        S    Aug22   1:09 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   12416  0.1  3.8 466764 39020 ?        S    Aug22   1:12 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   12417  0.1  4.3 474916 44180 ?        S    Aug22   1:09 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   12418  0.1  3.9 466596 40108 ?        S    Aug22   1:07 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   12419  0.1  4.1 483704 42392 ?        S    Aug22   1:08 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     12960  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug22   0:00 [kworker/u30:0]
apache   14977  0.7  4.2 485100 43372 ?        S    Aug21  24:02 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   14978  0.7  4.1 489860 42536 ?        S    Aug21  23:32 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   14979  0.7  4.3 484092 44816 ?        S    Aug21  23:51 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   14980  0.7  4.1 491120 42312 ?        S    Aug21  24:01 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   14981  0.7  4.1 491984 42732 ?        S    Aug21  23:34 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   14982  0.7  4.2 491680 43680 ?        S    Aug21  23:43 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   14983  0.7  4.1 491768 42404 ?        S    Aug21  23:28 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   14984  0.7  4.0 490436 41508 ?        S    Aug21  23:42 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   15030  0.7  4.3 486920 44224 ?        S    Aug21  23:39 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   15040  0.6  4.7 486704 48124 ?        S    Aug21  23:11 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   15343  0.6  4.0 484224 41632 ?        S    Aug21  22:56 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   16238  0.6  4.1 486556 41812 ?        S    Aug21  22:34 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     17169  0.0  0.6 115740  6536 ?        Ss   10:58   0:00 sshd: ec2-user [priv]
ec2-user 17171  0.0  0.5 115740  5140 ?        S    10:58   0:00 sshd: ec2-user@pts/0
ec2-user 17172  0.0  0.3 115476  3320 pts/0    Ss   10:58   0:00 -bash
ec2-user 17227  4.0  0.2 117204  2340 pts/0    R+   10:58   0:00 ps aux
ec2-user 21561  0.0  0.0 113084     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:00 /bin/sh /home/ec2-user/bin/startJayServer.sh
ec2-user 21562 49.2  7.2 2283928 73668 ?       Sl   Aug21 1393:33 java -server com.jayavon.game.server.MyServer -PROD
apache   24084  0.5  4.4 486596 45336 ?        S    Aug21  14:53 /usr/sbin/httpd
```

Comment: can you [edit] in the relevant output of `ps aux && free`?

Comment: Note also that MySQL Server [is often the victim](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/25171/11651), not the cause, of memory exhaustion issues.

Comment: @MattClark I have added in the outputs that you requested.  Sorry it took so long, I was sleeping.  Really appreciate your help!

Comment: From the output of `ps aux`, it would appear that all of your RAM is being eaten by _httpd_. In the printout, I can see ~19 httpd process consuming ~40MiB each =~ 750+MiB.

Comment: You may want to lookup tuning guides for httpd / apache(2).

Comment: Thanks Matt - I will look into that!  If you turn this into an answer I will mark it accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `top` will sort processes by CPU usage - so it would seem that whatever is eating all of your memory is not using much CPU time.

To sort [`top`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/top) by RESident memory, use

```
top -o RES
# or
top -o MEM

# commands may vary slightly depending on distros
```

In the printout of `ps aux` that you have provided, we can see that there are ~20 **httpd** process, each one consuming close to 40MiB =~ 800MiB of precious RAM.

You may want to look into tuning guides for httpd / apache2.